# Как управлять громкостью звука с помощью Python?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, аудио

Пишу программу по удаленному управлению ПК. Нужно добавить функцию управления звуком. Есть подходящая библиотека?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В Ubuntu, к примеру, так:

```
import alsaaudio # этот модуль надо предварительно установить: sudo apt-get install python-alsaaudio
mix = alsaaudio.Mixer() # инициализируем объект микшера
vol = mix.getvolume() # получили текущую громкость
mix.setvolume(90) # теперь пусть динамики поорут :) - установим громкость 90
```

Библиотека `python-alsaaudio` служит не только для управления микшера, она полезна для работы со звуком вообще

В Windows всё проще и сложнее. Проще, наверное скачать [библиотеку от Paradoxis](https://github.com/Paradoxis/Windows-Sound-Manager) и использовать ее:

```
from sound import Sound # будем использовать статические функции класса Sound
Sound.mute() # убрали звук
Sound.volume_max() # Наоборот, прибавили на максимум
cur = Sound.current_volume() # получили текущие настройки
vol = int(input("Введите громкость звука в единицах (0..100): ")) # получим громкость от пользователя
Sound.volume_set(vol) # установим пользовательскую громкость
Sound.volume_up() # увеличим громкость на 2 единицы (проценты говорить неправильно)
Sound.volume_down() # уменьшим громкость на 2 единицы
```

Answer (score 2):

Купил клавиатуру, на которой нет регулировки громкости,
поэтому сделал горячие клавиши. 
Эта программа, сочетаниями клавиш,
эмитирует нажатие кнопок управления звуком (на клавиатуре).

`#print(keyboard.read_hotkey()); input()` - Эту строку необходимо
раскомментировать, когда Вам надо прослушать горячие клавиши,
чтобы заменить их в коде "`*+-`" "`*+plus`" "`*+backspace`"

```
import keyboard #pip install keyboard
#print(keyboard.read_hotkey()); input()

keyboard.add_hotkey("*+-", lambda:keyboard.send("volume up"))
keyboard.add_hotkey("*+plus", lambda:keyboard.send("volume down"))
keyboard.add_hotkey("*+backspace", lambda:keyboard.send("volume mute"))

input()
```

или

```
import keyboard #pip install keyboard
#print(keyboard.read_hotkey()); input()

array = {
"*+-":"volume up",
"*+plus":"volume down",
"*+backspace":"volume mute"
}

def fun(str): keyboard.send(str)
for key in array: keyboard.add_hotkey(key, fun, args=[array[key]])
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

В модуле sound нет вообще класса Sound(был ли не смотрел)

Действующий вариант для Windows:

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

from random import randint

devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
    IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))


volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(0.2, None) #Где 0.2 это 20% громкость

current_volume = volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar() # Получить текущий уровень 
звука
```

соответственно плюс мину:

```
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar() + 0.1, 
None)
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar() - 0.1, 
None)
```