# Python | Регулирование звука мышью

Tags: python

Решил сделать регулировку звука на Windows 10 мышкой с дополнительными кнопками (ровно 2), так как на клавиатуре нет горячих клавиш.

Задача - при нажатии на первую доп. кнопку повышать звук и при нажатии на вторую соответственно уменьшать. Также при включении компьютера нужно автоматически запускать код.

[image: Пример мыши]

Какие библиотеки потребуются для выполнения этой задачи? Возникает вопрос, как обозначить доп. кнопки мыши например в pyautogui.

Comment: Можно глянуть тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773188/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-python
и тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828752/python-change-master-application-volume

Comment: Если мышь "программируемая" - т.е. изначально производитель побеспокоился о том, что вы захотите изменять бинды, макросы и пр... То это делается очень просто через софт той компании, чью мышь вы юзаете. На данном скрине logitech g102 - если у вас такая, то да, она легко "программируется" через родной софт, и переназначить эти клавиши не составляет труда и без python

Comment: У меня мышь DEXP Atropos.